# Circles and right angles

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, circles

The following is a standard fact about circles:

**THEOREM**:  Let $p$ and $q$ be two antipodal points on a circle in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and let $r$ be another point on the circle such that $r \neq p,q$.  Then the angle formed by the line segments $pr$ and $rq$ is a right angle.

It is easy enough to prove this theorem using cartesian coordinates, but I'm looking for synthetic proofs (as many as possible).  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The simplest is to consider the triangles $orp$ and $orq$. They are both isosceles because $or=op=oq$ as radius of the circle. Therefore the angles at their base are equal. Which means $\widehat{opr}=\widehat{orp}$ and $\widehat{oqr}=\widehat{orq}$. Besides in the triangle $prq$ one has

$$\widehat{pqr}+\widehat{qpr}+\widehat{prq}=\pi$$

and

$$\widehat{prq}=\widehat{orp}+\widehat{orq}=\widehat{qpr}+\widehat{pqr}$$

From those two equations we get $\widehat{prq}=\frac{\pi}{2}$

Answer (score 0):

The inscribed angle formed intercepts 180$^{\circ}$ of arc. So it's measure is $90^{\circ}.$[***See this***.](http://www.regentsprep.org/regents/math/geometry/gp15/circleangles.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Use the inscribed Angle Theorem

Comment: @HomegrownTomato How does this not answer the question? Because Antipodal points form a 180 degree arc, by using the inscribed angle theorem, we see that the angle is 180/2=90 degrees.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another argument. The statement of the theorem is suggesting that the answer does not depend on the choice of $r$ nor the choice of antipodal points $p$ and $q$. So assume this is indeed the case and let call $\alpha$ the angle between $pr$ and $rq$. Let $r'$ be the antipodal of $r$. Now, for instance, the angle between $rq$ and $qr'$ is again $\alpha$ because $r,r'$ are antipodal and $q \neq r,r'$. The same for the two other angles. So you get $4\cdot \alpha = 360^{\circ}$ and $\alpha = 90^{\circ}$.